# getting the HEAD element from overlay.js firefox plugin

Tags: javascript, firefox, plugins, element, head

I have a lightwiehgt plugin to firefox which needs to inject a script into the HTML.
The code looks like this:

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
var newscrpt;       
newscrpt = document.createElement('script');
newscrpt.type = "text/javascript" ;
newscrpt.src = "http://blabla.com/...";
newscrpt = head.appendChild(newscrpt);
```

The problem is that `document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]` returns 'undefined', and checking `document.getElementsByTagName("head").length` is 0.

It currently executes on the browser document.onLoad event but I also tried calling it from `window.setTimeout` to make sure it is not a problem with loading synchronization, but the same happens.

Any ideas from anyone?
Thanks!

Comment: might this be a greasemonkey userscript? in that case you may need to access `unsafeWindow.document` for, err, security reasons.

Comment: Nope. Not a greasemonkey script...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a `frame` or an `iframe` object, you should not reference the `document` directly but do something like:

```
    var doc = frame.contentWindow.document;
```

After that you can get the head. I'm using jQuery to add some resources to it:

```
    $(doc).find('head').append(
                '<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="MyStylesheet.css" />');
```

Hope it helps.